# Convergence of $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{(n!)^{1/n}}{n^2}$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

I am trying to detemine whether the following series converges:
$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{(n!)^{1/n}}{n^2}.$$

Since $(n^n)^{1/n} = n$, I assume $(n!)^{1/n} = o(n)$, but so far I failed to prove it.

I could not find any candidates for comparison test either.

I may not use Stirling's formula.

Any help will be appericiated.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut unfortunately I may not use stirling's.

Comment: @J.G. Ok, will try again.

Comment: Hint: $$
e^n  = 1 + n +  \ldots  + \frac{{n^n }}{{n!}} +  \ldots  \Longrightarrow e^n  \ge \frac{{n^n }}{{n!}} \Longrightarrow (n!)^{1/n}  \ge \frac{n}{e}
$$

Comment: @Gary Ok nice. this led me to a simple and elegant solution. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Even if you're not allowed to use Stirling, it is still a useful result to know in the sense that it may lead you to a (non-Stirling) solution. Informally, in its simplest form Stirling's approximation says that $n!\sim \left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n$.  Substituting this into your series gives $\sum \frac{1}{ne}$ so we know the series must diverge as it is the harmonic series up to multiplication by a constant. To prove this, use the limit comparison test:
$$\frac{\frac{(n!)^{1/n}}{n^2}}{\frac{1}{n}}=\frac{(n!)^{1/n}}{n}=\left(\frac{n!}{n^n}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}$$
Let $a_n = \frac{n!}{n^n}$. If we show that $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\to L$ it then follows that $\sqrt[n]a_n\to L$ as well.

Can you show that $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\to\frac{1}{e}$? If so, by limit comparison your series will then diverge.

Comment: Yes indeed. I just started to read the proof of stirling's formula to get some ideas on how to solve it. thanks.